# URLS from website domain with "hidden" layers

Tags: web, url, beautifulsoup, request

I can not find a way to extract ALL URLs from the following website domains:

(1) https://www.ah.nl/zoeken?query=vegan

(2) https://www.jumbo.com/zoeken/?searchTerms=vegan

For the first, the problem is that the product are 'hidden' and as website visitor you need to select a button at the bottom page to show more items. I tried BeautifulSoup, but it does not extract the 'hidden' URLs.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import pandas

req = Request('https://www.ah.nl/zoeken?query=vegan')

html_page = urlopen(req)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")

df = pandas.DataFrame()
links = []
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    links.append(link.get('href'))
```

With the second website link, the issue is that there are multiple pages. Something that the previous code also does not work for. In a previous question, it was suggested to use:

```
url = 'https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/groceries-api/gol-services/product/v1/product'
payload ={
'filter[keyword]': 'vegan',
'include[PRODUCT_AD]': 'citrus',
'page_number': '1',
'page_size': '2000',
'sort_order': 'FAVOURITES_FIRST'
 }

jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
products = jsonData['products']

df = pd.DataFrame(products)
```

I have, however, not yet worked with request and parameters, and cannot figure out how to adjust these parameters to work with link (2).

Hopefully someone can help me with these 2 website links. Thank you.

Comment: in first website you have api, for example - https://www.ah.nl/zoeken/api/products/search?page=1&size=36&query=vegan

Comment: second website have graphql - https://www.jumbo.com/api/graphql

Comment: do you need to explain how to work with it?

Comment: @SergeyK No, I do not need to explain it. But I do know how it works. Thank you for the examples! I will look into api and graphql to learn about the background of these functions.

Comment: The items you have send do not open, but for these two methods you change the URLs itself right? And because of the parameters multiple searches are performed?

Comment: Also, it seems that it still does not include all hidden items when using API for the first one

Answer (score 0):

ah.nl site:

First of all, we must get the number of pages from the request. Further on the cycle we get each page. For example, I output data to the console, these are Title, Price and Link.

```
import requests
import json    


def get_data(query):
        page_size = 36
        url = f"https://www.ah.nl/zoeken/api/products/search?page=1&size={page_size}&query={query}"
        response = requests.request("GET", url, proxies=proxies)
        json_obj = json.loads(response.text)
        for page in range(int(json_obj['page']['totalPages'])):
            url = f"https://www.ah.nl/zoeken/api/products/search?page={page}&size={page_size}&query={query}"
            response = requests.request("GET", url)
            json_obj = json.loads(response.text)
            for products in json_obj['cards']:
                for product in products['products']:
                    print(product['title'], product['price']['now'], product['link'])
    
    
    get_data('vegan')
```

If you have any questions, I'll be happy to answer. If you need a code example with a second site, write, I will do

Comment: Thank you! I am still trying to work on the 2nd myself first. Still new with request, so a little bit of struggling would mean learning I guess. 

For this one: proxies=proxies. Yet, proxies is not defined. However, when I do not use  proxies, it works until it stops running providing the error:     

for products in json_obj['cards']:

KeyError: 'cards'